# Ruby on Rails 3: Session issue: Loosing content

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session

i have an error but i can't pinpoint the source :(  it works fine the first time i use the add_to_cart action, but the second time i have this error raising.

```
Started GET "/home/add_to_cart?id=5&money=USD" for 10.0.1.3 at 2013-05-26 17:22:42 +0200
 Processing by HomeController#add_to_cart as HTML
 Parameters: {"id"=>"5", "money"=>"USD"}
 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass):
  app/models/cart.rb:14:in `add_artwork'
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:39:in `add_to_cart'
```

it seems the object @cart is lost or something.... or the object 'artwork' is lost... i don't know...

the controller

```
def add_to_cart
  artwork = Artwork.find(params[:id])
  @cart = find_or_create_cart
  @cart.add_artwork(artwork)   #--- line 39
  redirect_to(:action => 'show_cart')
end

def show_cart
  @cart = find_or_create_cart
end

private

def find_or_create_cart
  session[:cart] ||= Cart.new
end
```

cart.rb

```
class Cart

  attr_reader :items
  attr_reader :total_price

  def initialize
     @items = []
     @total_price = 0.0
  end

  def add_artwork( artwork )
    @items << LineItem.new_based_on(artwork)
    @total_price += artwork.price   #---- line 14
  end
end
```

line_item.rb

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :artwork
  belongs_to :order

  def self.new_based_on ( artwork  )
    line_item = self.new
    line_item.artwork = artwork
    line_item.price = artwork.price
    return line_item
  end
end
```

session_store.rb

```
  Larrabyblaine::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was the object artwork wich was too big and caused a bug.

if i replace the

```
 line_item.artwork = artwork
```

by (wich corresponding modification in the database)

```
 line_item.title = artwork.title
```

it works perfectly. if anyone has an idea on the question how to manage big objects with session, i'm all hears.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `+=` on `@total_price` without an initiated value.

Just add a line before Line 14

```
@total_price ||= 0 
@total_price += artwork.price   #---- line 14
```

Comment: sorry but nope. the @total_price is initiated in the 'initialize' action.

Comment: i have tried to comment the line 14 to see what happens and i get an 'dump format error for symbol(0x7b)' error that crash the app. i had to remove the corresponding session from the database to rework.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
@total_price = if @total_price 
@total_price += artwork.price
else
artwork.price
end
```